# Clear mesh relationships/ Unparent

Tags: animation, rigging, objects, constraints, parent

[image: Parented object]

My problem is the glasses seem to be parented to the cube from the blue dotted line. I must have done it accidentally. I tried to clear parent the normal way (Object-Clear-Parent) but nothing. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the outliner with all of the folder open?  Also of the selected object's Object data properties with the relationship folder open?

Comment: Are you sure it's parented? It might be an object constraint.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually a constraint I must have put there